# I have an error when trying to migrate Laravel database

Tags: php, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, migration

I am an absolute beginner in Laravel (v 5.7.2) and I am facing my first real obstacle.
On MAMP, after successfully creating a database via phpmyadmin and a model `php artisan make:model [modelname] -m`, when i try to migrate it `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error:

> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]")
>         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/loginsystemLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68
>
> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=lsapp", "root", "", [])
>         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/loginsystemLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

I double checked the files **.env** and **database.php** and they ALL have the same configurations.

What is happening?

Comment: could be because mysql version is not supported by laravel. Can u change the db authentication method? ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';

Comment: What port is MySQL using in MAMP?

Comment: Looks like downvoting a question is the norm here...
Thank yoiu guys for your answers. I am using default port 3306, connection type is socket, although I am not sure if I have to write something there. Also I tried both with HostName localhost and 127.0.0.1 without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it myself by coincidence. I realized I had both version of mysql installed, mysql8 and mysql57. The first one supports by default cachin sha2 which is not yet supported by laravel. Possible solutions:

1)Change default mysql login method.
2) Use 5.7.
3) Remember to set the same parameters in .env and config/database.php files.

Hope this will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

just look in the .env File what DB_Name
Goto phpmyadmin and create a new Database ("Laravel") in my case